# iOS 13 UITableViewCell | Child view gets clipped out

Tags: ios12, ios13, xcode11, swift5

SO I have a `UITableView` which contains a `UITableViewCell` and `tableView.header` is set to a Parallax Header. The `UITableViewCell` has certain `UIView`s which are set as negative constraints from Top and are shown perfectly on **iOS-12** whereas when observed on **iOS-13** the `UIView`s showing over Parallax Header are clipped. I have tried all possible solutions but unfortunately it still shows the same. My App is opting out of SwiftUI and still running the old code. I have even tried to change the `zIndex` of the child `UIView` but still the same. Here are some snapshots and some code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    self.PriceView.layer.zPosition = 1
    self.PriceView.bringSubviewToFront(self.contentView)
    self.PriceView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

This code is functional for **iOS-12** but not **iOS-13**.

**UPDATE:**

Apple's changelog/documentation for **iOS-13** suggests:

> The UITableViewCell class’s contentView property is always laid out
>   edge-to-edge with adjacent accessories, both on the leading and the
>   trailing side. This streamlines the layout code so developers who want
>   the correct default offset no longer have to align their content with
>   the content view border or the layout margin depending on whether
>   there is an accessory on the trailing side or not. You should now
>   always lay out their code on the layout margins of the cell’s content
>   view to get the default system insets. These insets will be adjusted
>   automatically based on the accessories visible in the cell to match
>   the system’s default spacing. (48214114)

This is a bit unclear to me and if someone can help me out here.

Here are the snapshots as to how it is showing in **iOS-12** which is required and how it is showing in **iOS-13** respectively:

[image]

And here observe for **iOS-13**:

[image]

Here is also the Constraint Layout of my `UITableViewCell`'s `PriceView`:

[image]

I need both to be consistent on both OSes. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wohoo! I finally figured it out. So before as default it was working on **iOS-12** but after **iOS-13** and `UITableViewCell` changes as described in the question, it stopped working. Here is what I did:

1. Firstly, in the **Size Inspector**, the `ContentView` of `UITableViewCell` was set to `Safe Area Layout Guide` which I turned off and turned on `Safe Area Relative Margins`, similarly I did the same for the child, as in the **PriceView**.
2. Secondly, in the **Attributes Inspector**, the `ContentView`'s and `UITableViewCell`'s both had their `Autoresize Subviews` property turned on, I simply turned it off

And voila! It works. Hope anyone who might have these `UITableViewCell` issues, please note that now its all relative

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what worked for me was unchecking "clip to bounds" from the attribute inspector for the content view